# Japanese character do not display on Windows 7

Tags: windows, unicode, fonts

Even though my *Installed languages* include Japanese (in Control Panel\Region and Language\Keyboards and Languages\Installed Languages), and I have some *Japanese fonts* in my c:\windows\fonts directory, and my available updates do not include Japanese (in Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Update\Restore Hidden Updates), 
still - Japanese characters show as squares/Unicode on my system, viz.

[image]
[image: How Japanese is displayed in Firefox]

I also tried to change my *Locale* to Japan: that didn't help either.

***Can you suggest how to make Japanese Kanji etc. display on my Windows 7 ?***

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Does the same happen with Firefox?

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes

The top screen-capture is from Chrome, the bottom is from Firefox.

Comment: Dunno about Chrome. Chrome is sorta crappy in this matter. In FF, go to options, 'Content', then under 'Fonts & Colors' click 'Advanced...', and change the 'Fonts for' dropdown to 'Japanese' and make sure the fonts there are appropriate.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes Followed you advice, and discovered that all my Japanese fonts were unusable. Installed a new Japanese font and now FF displays Japanese (yay!). I'll try and do the same now for Chrome. Thanks Martinho.

Comment: For completeness sake - to set Japanese support in Chrome: go to chrome://settings/, 'Show advanced settings...', 'Web Content', 'Customize Fonts', Change 'Encoding' (e.g., to "Japanese (Shift_JIS)", and set all fonts to a (Japanese) font.